# SQL script to get time to response in log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I have one scenario which I really have no idea how to write SQL command.I have one log table which keeps data from users and admins.Users do transactions such as insert or edit etc. For edit,it could be more than one times before admin approved. Admins do approve or reject for those user transactions. I want to know how fast admin response to user.

Let see the transaction for user A.

Log table

```
Insert 20/01/2014 11:30:00 -->User trans 1
Approve 20/01/2014 11:40:05 -->Admin trans 1 responses to User trans 1
Edit 20/01/2014 12:00:01 -->User trans 2 -> first transaction after admin approved
Edit 20/01/2014 12:05:10 -->User trans 3
Approve 20/01/2014 12:06:45 -->Admin trans 2 responses to User trans 2 and 3
Edit 20/01/2014 13:01:56 -->User trans 4 -> first transaction after admin approved
Edit 20/01/2014 14:34:00 -->User trans 5
Approve 20/01/2013 14:43:00 -->Admin trans 3 responses to User trans 4 and 5
Edit 20/01/2014 15:55:43 -->User trans 6 -> first transaction after admin approved
Approve 20/01/2014 16:01:00 -->Admin trans 4 response to User trans 6
```

To calculate time to response for this scenario

Admin trans 1 response to User trans 1 then time to response is 11:40:05-11:30:00

Admin trans 2 response to User trans 2 and 3 but we calculate time to response from the first user transaction after admin approved then time to response is 12:06:45-12:00:01

Admin trans 2 response to User trans 2 and 3 but we calculate time to response from the first user transaction after admin approved then time to response is 14:43:00-13:01:56

Admin trans 2 response to User trans 2 then time to response is 16:01:00-15:55:43

Table structure

uuid    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
referer STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
item_id INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
member_id   INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
admin_id    INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
cate_id INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
listing_status  INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
monitor_status  INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
note    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
txn_type    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ip_address  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
email   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
post_name   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
user_agent  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
timestamp   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
http_host   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
type    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_name STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_os   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_patch    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_os_major STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_os_minor STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_os_name  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_build    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_device   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_major    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
ua_minor    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
log_source  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
timestamp_int   INTEGER NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip   RECORD  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.ip    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.country_code2 STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.country_code3 STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.country_name  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.continent_code    STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.region_name   STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.city_name STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.latitude  FLOAT   NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.longitude FLOAT   NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.timezone  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...
geoip.real_region_name  STRING  NULLABLE
Describe this field...

Please guide

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have additional columns in the Log table? What is the pk?

Comment: problem is understood,but infi is incomlete.please table structure with few sample data.Most probably use datediff in second.

Comment: Hi Nathan, There is no pk for this table

Comment: Hi KumarHarsh, I have updated table structure but could not paste sample data cause it's too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you can match an "approval" to the "edit" it approves, then you should be able to self-join your table to join these into a single row. Once the approval and edit are on the same row, you can calculate the difference to find the approval delay.

Something like this (replace approve.approve_id = edit.edit_id with whatever you use to match an approval log line to the first edit log line it is associated with):

```
SELECT approve.timestamp - edit.timestamp as delay
  FROM
    [table] AS approve
    JOIN [table] as edit
    ON approve.approve_id = edit.edit_id
```

Comment: Hi Michael, there is no id that the problem.